# Change \n or \r into <br/>

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I have a string I am getting back from an API that looks like this:

```
[{"lat":"39.142971","lng":"-77.215924","hours":"Monday - Wednesday: 11:30am to 11:00pm\r\nThursday: 11:00am to 11:00pm\r\nFriday-Saturday: 11:00am to 12:00am\r\nSunday: 11:30am to 10:00pm","phone":"3019634847","name":"DFH Alehouse, Gaithersburg"}]
```

When I parse the hours I am running it through this to make new lines when I display it on a web page:

```
hours = hours.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, "<br/>");
```

But when it displays, it is not inserting the line breaks. The odd thing to me is that when I store my own data in a my database and I type it with \n the above code works. But now when I am taking it from the api.

Comment: Data is returned from a php script I wrote

Comment: Don't do this. Instead, format the string using CSS properties such as `white-space`, which will do the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript parses `\r\n` automatic to line breaks. so your regex should look for line breaks (instead of strings). It should look like this:

```
hours = hours.replace(/\r\n|\n|\r/g,'<br/>');
```

`/\r\n|\n|\r/g` This is the "final solution". It first looks for carriage return and linebreak paired, the only line breaks and then carriage returns. (This was inspired by @torazaburo)

As @torazaburo said, you probably shouldn't edit the text, instead you should just add `white-space:pre;` to your container. This is less resource intensive and uses a more "vanilla" way.

Comment: Why do you think JS throws away `\r` for some reason?

Comment: Workes like a champ, thanks!

Comment: This goes back to MS-DOS. to be backward compatible. it has something to do with printers. It is outdated, but good practice.

Comment: @Le'nton the truth is that `\r` is still there, your solution lefts the redundant `\r` character there in the string. And it's sad OP chosen this solution even though it produces garbage. "It is outdated, but good practice" --- unless it's not.

Comment: carriage return is ignored by HTML. but if you are looking to put this into an `pre` node, just extend the regex to `/\r\n/gm` I will put this in the answer.

Comment: The `m` flag is irrelevant here. It means something entirely different, namely to interpret anchors (`^` and `$`) in terms of lines within the string. More importantly, you cannot tell what newline convention data coming from the server is going to be following. It might be `\r\n`, it might be `\r`, or it might be `\n`. A correct solution must account for all of these.

Comment: @torazaburo is it okay like this?

Comment: @Le'nton Looks fine, thanks. Except normally `pre-wrap` or `pre-line` works better as a value for `white-space`.

Comment: @torazaburo but in this case it's not relevant. It only matters when there are leading whitespaces. Right?

Comment: No, it handles runs of whitespace differently. `pre` will keep groups of spaces, whereas `pre-wrap` etc. will condense them down to one as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression tries to find a backslash then 'r' or 'n'.

Try instead:

`/[\n\r]{0,2}/g`

which find all newlines or carriage-return

Comment: This will convert `\r\n` to 2 `<br>`s

Comment: `|\r` is not necessary, since carriage returns and linebreaks allways go together.

Comment: @Le'nton it is necessary, please stop spreading this bs. "since carriage returns and linebreaks allways go together" --- this is simply wrong.

Comment: my fault. unix uses only `\n`

Comment: @zerkms you're right, edited it

Comment: And now it will convert `\n\n` to just a single `<br>` :-)